# Redux flow for a dynamic realtime api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm seeking for a bit of reference regarding redux; because of support for several different platforms (Java Android, ios swift, ios Obj-c, go, Node.js, and web javascript) I have mocked up a solution for realtime app management.

The explanation on how this work is quite extensive but it's basically a rest endpoint which data can be parsed and it's specifically designed to produce a simple realtime api manager and resource fetcher that works the same way accross platforms (this is the JS example); eg.

```
API.fromURL('https://api.mysite.com/v1').then(loadApi).catch(...);

function loadAPI(api){
   if (!api.user){
     api.login('user','password').then(()=>{
        workWithAPI(api);
     }).catch(...);
   } else {
      workWithAPI(api);
   }
}

function workWithAPI(api){
   console.log(api.user);
   api.user.on('update',(event)=>{
     console.log(event.name === api.user.name); //true
     //changes happen even if you don't have a listener
   });

   if (!api.user.isSubscribed()){
      api.user.subscribe().then(()=>{
         api.user.setName(...).then...;
         save(api.serialize());
      }).catch(...);
   } else {
      api.user.setName(...).then...;
      save(api.serialize());
   }
}

API.fromData(...).then(loadApi).catch(...);
```

The great thing is that this api object represents the state of the objects it contains, so if you have an user object it will always keep on sync with the database and reflect the changes via events that are sent from the server.

Question is how to apply this idea to the redux concept in the browser context in an efficient way?...

Considering:

1. That all the objects contained in the api object exist in the store; but there can be app states that are ui related that do not exist in the api object state.
2. That the api object and all what it contains is mutable, and redux works better on immutability.
3. That the api object is serializable much like a store.
4. That the api object is a tree, and it's not good practice to use such in the redux model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync your API State in your Store state.
In order to do that, the best way, in my opinion, is to rewrite or to integrate your API object inside Redux, as an external action creator.

So here is how I would do it (considering you didn't mention React):

I would maintain a subtree for metadata about the connection:

```
{ connecting: false, authenticated: true, status: 'CONNECTED' }
```

This way, you can handle if your connection goes down, or whatever.
Give it also some actions to mutate this state.

```
const actions = { reconnectToAPI, logIn, logOut, connectionLost }
```

(those are items are actions creators, I used ES6 syntax for the object, `{ reconnectToAPI }` is the same as `{ reconnectToAPI: reconnectToAPI }`)

Now, bind those metadata to your events.

```
connection.on('lost', reason => {
  dispatch(connectionLost(reason))
  dispatch(reconnectToAPI())
})
```

logIn would be a [thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) which would authenticate you using a username and a password through your API.

```
const logIn = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  return api.authenticate(username, password)
  .then(profile => {
    dispatch(loggedIn(profile))
  }, error => {
    dispatch(failedToLogIn(error))
  })
}
```

Next, you map your state to your others tree.
I would suggest doing a store enhancer or a middleware to do this.
Give it also some actions, or auto-generate them if you need it.